Scrape Google Search Results Python BeautifulSoup
I have a query for google, which show me 8000 results with link, I only want to scrape links(urls) in search results, I am able to get first page links, Is there any method to scrape next pages. Here is my code


for page in range(0,7):
    linkedin_urls = [url.text for url in linkedin_urls]
    #print(linkedin_urls)
        #loop to iterate through all links in the google search query
    for gol_url in linkedin_urls:
        print(gol_url)
        #driver.get(Xmen_url)
        #sel = Selector(text = driver.page_source)
        sleep(3)
         #Go back to google search
        driver.get('https://www.gooogle.com')
        sleep(3)
        #locate search form by name
        search_query = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'q')
        sleep(3)
        #Input search words
        search_query.send_keys('inurl:https://www.ama-assn.org/system/files')

        #Simulate return key
        search_query.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    #find next page icon in Google search
    #Next_Google_page = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Next").click()
    Next_Google_page = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Next").click()

    page += 1




There is no pagination now in google search but instead infinite scrolling. You need to scroll till the end of the page and wait for it to load more results automatically until you reach the end where you have to click 'more results' to see more result.

Here is a sample code using selenium to scroll till the end of google search.
import time
from selenium import webdriver
search_query_link = 'google_search_query_link'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(search_query_link)
current_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
page_end = True
while page_end:
      driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")   
      time.sleep(5)
      new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
      if current_height == new_height:
            page_end = False
      else:
            current_height = new_height
# Your code to extract all the links goes here
driver.quit()

You can further wrap this code in a loop to click on 'more results' every time you encounter it.

Thanks alot, working fine. but my BeautifulSoup still scraping 10 results, any idea how to get others

When you use beautiful soup, you get the html content of the page via requests.get() method. The thing to be noted here is, in this case when you recieve the html content of the google search page, only limited results are loaded at the time. Even if you scroll down to the maximum length and load all the result, by using beautiful soup you'll receive html context from the beginning itself, as if you've just visited the page (with few results in display). Alternatively you could try and use selenium to get all the links dynamically.

thanks, Ammar, Will you please send me example of selenium code getting all the link dynamically. Thanks alot for your kind help.

Do you need all the links (a tags) that appear in your Google search ?

yes, I need all links which appear in search tag, about 8000 search results.
